# How do I process two functions in parallel each running at a specific frequency?

Tags: c++, multithreading, time

I would like to run two functions in parallel, each having a different execution frequency.

I used [CppTime::Timer](https://github.com/eglimi/cpptime), but I realized, that the functions are actually executed behind each other. Is that because `CppTime` executes the threads behind each other, or is there something wrong with my code?

Here the script:

```
CppTime::Timer timer;
std::vector<CppTime::timer_id> timer_id;

timer_id.push_back(timer.add(std::chrono::seconds(0), &longProcess, std::chrono::milliseconds(static_cast<unsigned>(1000.0 / frequency_slow))));
timer_id.push_back(timer.add(std::chrono::seconds(0), &shortProcess, std::chrono::milliseconds(static_cast<unsigned>(1000.0 / frequency_high))));
```

Does someone know the error or maybe someone has another solution than CppTime?

Edit:
One process should run at `1Hz` (needs approximately `0.5s`). The other process should run at `10Hz` (needs only a few `ms`). It is no problem if they do not run in parallel, and the `10Hz` process starts after `0.5s`.

Comment: Multithreading doesn't execute code in exactly parallel time automagically. Even not if running on different cores necessarily (Clock maybe a shared HW device). Question is which minimum time gap would be acceptable for your requirements?

Comment: Since `CppTime` is clearly some library you have obtained from somewhere or written yourself, it's important to include extra details about it.  Don't assume that anyone here has used this before, or that they will take the time to hunt it down on the internet simply because you left that information out.

Comment: @paddy it appears to be [this implementation](https://github.com/eglimi/cpptime)

Comment: What do you want to achieve by running two thread aligned in time simultaneously?

Comment: A simple control loop, with a high-level and low-level controller.

Comment: ok actually that's true, time alignment is not really necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When adding the timer callbacks, the statements `longProcess()` and `shortProcess()` will try to *call* those functions, and then pass the return values to `add()`.  So the 1st `timer.add()` wouldn't even be executed until after `longProcess()` finishes its work and exits.  And the same with the 2nd `timer.add()` and `shortProcess()`.

Assuming the code even compiles at all, given that `add()` expects callbacks that match the signature of `handler_t`, which is defined as `std::function<void(timer_id)>`, but you are calling the callbacks without any parameters.

Get rid of the parenthesis when passing the callback functions to `add()`:

```cpp
void longProcess(CppTime::timer_id)
{
    ...
}

void shortProcess(CppTime::timer_id)
{
    ...
}

...

CppTime::Timer timer;
std::vector<CppTime::timer_id> timer_id;

timer_id.push_back(timer.add(std::chrono::seconds(0), &longProcess, std::chrono::milliseconds(static_cast<unsigned>(1000.0 / frequency_slow))));
timer_id.push_back(timer.add(std::chrono::seconds(0), &shortProcess, std::chrono::milliseconds(static_cast<unsigned>(1000.0 / frequency_high))));
```

That being said, looking at the [actual implementation](https://github.com/eglimi/cpptime/blob/master/cpptime.h), the `CppTime::Timer` class runs a single worker thread internally.  It stores the added timers in a sorted vector, and just loops through that vector in a continuous loop, executing each handler when its time period elapses.  So, it doesn't really matter how many timers you add, their handlers will always execute sequentially in relation to each other.  So, to do what you are attempting, you will need to to separate your handlers into multiple `CppTime::Timer` instances so that you have multiple threads running.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The code is actually working (but yes without parenthesis), but as you said it executes sequentially. Do you know how I have to change it to execute it in parallel?

Comment: @gab: `CppTime` has a single thread it uses for timers, and does not offer built-in multi-threading. You'll have to do the multi-threading yourself. Create a thread-pool, and have the timers execute the work in the thread-pool, instead of in the callback directly.